# Should I host my website data and database on different server

Tags: amazon-web-services, server

I am currently getting 900 to 1200 unique views daily and it is constantly increasing. Right now everything is setup on vps as using cloudflare as cdn

So I am thinking to shift my storage to aws S3 and database to AWS RDS so my vps will only run php files.

Since all the server update patches are done by vps provider , so I don't want to use EC2 since I am not a server type guy and managing it and security will be problem for me.

Will this setup be good in term of scaling and speed and if I upload data on S3 will cloudlflare serve it as cdn

My website is social network type so image are upload and use very much

Thanks it will be great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always keep your database as close as possible to the database to reduce latency. It would not be a good idea to put them in separate data centers.

You probably should keep your database on a separate server (in the same data center) so that it can scale separately to your application, and also to make backups more manageable.

I'm not sure what you mean by "shift my storage to aws S3", but if you are referring to the serving of static images, then this is quite feasible. However, you would be responsible for configuring your application and CDN.

Answer (score 0):

You can see if [AWS Lightsail](https://aws.amazon.com/lightsail/features/) is more suitable for your needs.

It has a LAMP stack and RDS and S3 packaged as a nice service, to begin with. It will be less of a hassle to set up your own services.

And as all pieces of your VPS, S3, RDS, Loadbalancer will reside on AWS ecosystem, it will be more efficient.

https://aws.amazon.com/lightsail/faq/